# Socket Response issue in iOS Socket Programming

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, serversocket, asyncsocket

I am developing app like Client/Driver.

In my application, We have used `socket programming` to track driver.

For tracking, Driver app will sent location(lat,lng) after every 5 seconds using socket and Client app will listen that socket response and update driver location.

This works fine, But my issue is :-

Sometimes client app get bad response as below :-

[image: Socket Response]

Means, bunch of responses in single socket response, and i can't handle this response.

Can anyone help me why i am getting this type of response, even i am sending single socket request every time from driver app at a time?

Hope for best.

Thank you.

Comment: Ideally socket programming is used for broadcast purpose. For example 1 driver is connected to socket and provide their presence on that, now again you provide presence on socket without connecting again. So what happens when you get list of present drivers same driver presence id you will get twice of time. Now i hope you understand what would be problem.

Comment: @Hasya :- Thanks for support. Can you please tell me what do you mean presence?

Comment: Your problem is driver id "109" is having multiple location on socket , right ?

Comment: @Hasya :- Nope dear.. User Id - 109 sending one request at every 5 second. Now Client get that response multiple times with different location.

Comment: Yes, because your old request is available on socket broadcast as it is so client is getting multiple location. You have to ask your back end developer who has maintained socket, ask them to check if 109 id location is available then update that location and send 1 single on socket or delete previous one and send new one. so client will get only 1 location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically socket is used to broadcast data.

This happened, because your old request is available on socket broadcast as it is, so client is getting multiple location. You have to ask your back end developer who has maintained socket, ask them to check if 109 id location is available then update that location and send 1 single on socket or delete previous one and send new one. So client will get only 1 location.

Quick turn around you can do as set request time to 10 seconds instead of 5 seconds, each time when you want to send location. make connection to socket, send location and disconnect. Repeat this things at each time.

Nothing seems wrong at iOS code side, mostly you have to maintain at back end side.

You just need maintain proper architecture for this.

Comment: Thanks Hasya for support and help.

Comment: Welcome, if it is worth for you then please accept my answer. contact me if you need any further assistance.